# SQL Server 2005 using identifier from previous join statment

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table with 2 columns, the first is PKey, the second is an identifier; BAN & IID respectively.

I am looking to pull out the top 2 IID's for every distinct BAN. I used a sub-query in the From  to get the Max(IID) which works fine. However when I try to join the table to my 1st statement to get the next highest MAX(IID) I get:

"Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "ii.iid" could not be bound."

This is referring to the Where statement in my 2nd join "where iid  < ii.iid"

```
select distinct ii.BAN, ii.IID, ii2.IID
    from (select distinct BAN, IID = Max(IID) from Bill_Timeliness..Invoices with(nolock) group by BAN) II
    join (select distinct BAN, IID = Max(IID) from Bill_Timeliness..Invoices with(nolock) where iid  < ii.iid group by BAN) II2 
        on ii.ban = ii2.ban
```

I have tried re-creating the first part as a second subquery of the where statement.

I also tried where iid  < max(ii.iid)

Neither of these worked....i would really appreciate if someone can help me out here.

-Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
select o.BAN, 
       x.MaxID as TopID, 
       MAX(case when o.IID != x.MaxID then o.IID else null end) as SecondID
from (
    select BAN, MAX(IID) as MaxID
    from Bill_Timeliness..Invoices group by BAN) x
inner join Bill_Timeliness..Invoices o
on x.BAN = o.BAN
group by o.BAN,
         x.MaxID
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not how aliases are scoped
You could try a CTE instead.

```
;with CTE_X as (
select BAN, IID, dense_rank() over (partition by BAN order by IID desc) as ranker from    Bill_Timeliness..Invoices)


select I.BAN, I.IID, II.IID from CTE_X I inner join CTE_X II on
I.BAN = II.BAN and I.ranker = 1 and II.ranker = 2
```